# C# + SQL Multible table Insert

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, insert

First, I'm sorry for bad English :)
 
I need help in the way I have mentioned in the title, thank you very much to interested friends already.
 
MY QUESTION :

There are tables as follows:

CARIKART, (keeps the basic current card information)

CARIKARTNUFUS, (Keeps the population information of the same current card)

CARIKARTESNUFUS, (caricart's wife keeps population information)

CARIKARTREFERANSNUFUS, (keeps the population information of the reference card of the current card (the proposer / guarantor)
 
These tables are related to each other by ID and the information of all is collected at CARIKART.

The event I want to do now,

When data is inserted into the tables CARIKARTNUFUS, CARIKARTNUFUSES and CARIKARTNUFUSREFERANS, the IDs are automatically written (insert) to CARIKART.

Thanks for interesting,
Best Regards,

Comment: What is your *exact* problem? You've written pretty long text, but haven't included the most important - your code sample and error message you're getting. So it is almost impossible to answer such a "question".

Comment: It will be much helpful if you could provide with some codes you have tried.